# Google Books API used in android application

Tags: android, google-api

I am using google books API in my android app to get books.User search the keyword and max 20 results are to be shown in the listview but my app shows different no of books for the same word every time I search.Suppose if I search "the" sometimes it shows 5 results and sometimes 4.

```
public class BooksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Books>> {
    private BooksAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mEmptyTextView;
    private EditText mEditText;
    public String searchString;

    public static final String LOG_TAG = BooksActivity.class.getName();
    public static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
    public static  String BOOKS_URL =  "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?maxResults=20&q=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listing_books);
        mEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_keyword);
        Button searchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        final ListView booksListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mEmptyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        booksListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyTextView);
        mAdapter = new BooksAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Books>());
        booksListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        booksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Books currentBook = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Uri bookUri = Uri.parse(currentBook.getmUrl());
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, bookUri);
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEditText.clearFocus();
               //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                String searchQuery = mEditText.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "+");
                if (searchQuery != null && !searchQuery.equals("")) {

                    searchString = BOOKS_URL + searchQuery;
                    ConnectivityManager connMangr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMangr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID,null,BooksActivity.this);
                    } else {
                        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
                        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEmptyTextView.setText("No Internet Connection");
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }
    public Loader<List<Books>> onCreateLoader(int i,Bundle bundle)
    {
     return  new BooksLoader(this,searchString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Books>> loader, List<Books> data) {
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           mAdapter.clear();
        mEmptyTextView.setText(R.string.noDataFound);
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(data);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Books>> loader) {
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: what is your expectation? what have you already done and what do you expect the result to be? share that, please.

Comment: My question is why is it showing different no of results each time

Comment: I expect that it should show same no of books each time

Comment: share your code block and may be we can try debugging from there.

Comment: The code is neither showing any errors nor exceptions and the app is also working without crash but the result is not as I am expecting.

Comment: btw....the documentation also mentions that you should provide API key as well but your code doesnt have that. I am just pointing this one out.

Comment: But why do I need API key in this url?

Comment: I have made a similar app in which I used a url which gives me the data of recent earthquakes . In that app too I havent used API key to get data and the app is working fine. Then why do I need API key for this API ?

Comment: This looks more like a question that should be redirected to the API owner, not a programming question.

Comment: Are you saying this is not a programming error?